# How to use AND in laravel database query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$konten = Konten::all()->where('kategori','Announcement' AND 'kategori','Activities')->sortByDesc('id');
```

It's not work what is the right query for using AND Logic in query sir ? im so sorry i don't have much knowledge to find out the way.. the point is i want $konten contains the row from Konten where the kategori is Announcement and Activities.. how to make it happen ? it just showing konten where the kategori is activities the announcement not passed..

Comment: You can chain multiple `where()`. Also you don't need to use `all()`.
`Konten::where('kategori', 'Announcement')->where('kategori', 'Activites')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

You can chain several `where` to achieve `AND`:

```php
$konten = Konten::where('kategori', 'Announcement')
    ->where('kategori', 'Activities')
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Or use `whereIn` like this:

```php
$konten = Konten::whereIn('kategori', ['Announcement', 'Activities'])
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve an `AND` in Laravel, you simply chain `->where()` calls:

```
$konten = Konten::where('kategori','Announcement')->where('kategori','Activities') ...
```

As a side note, `Konten::all()` returns a `Collection`, and is no longer database logic. You shouldn't call `::all()` unless you specifically need every record in the database.

Refactor to the following:

```
$konten = Konten::where('kategori','Announcement')
->where('kategori','Activities')
->orderBy('id', 'desc')
->get();
```

This will leverage the database to perform the filtering/ordering, instead of offloading every record into a `Collection` and allowing `PHP` to perform the same logic, which can be incredibly inefficient depending on the number of records.

Comment: No problem! Instead of leaving a comment on every answer that helped, please consider upvoting them (use the up arrow above the 0 next to each answer), when when you can, press the checkmark to accept one and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$konten = Konten::whereIn('kategori', ['Announcement', 'Activities'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong feeling that you probably seek for 'orWhere' clause... If you want ALL records when kategori column equals 'Announcement' and all records when kategori equals 'Activities' you sholud use orWhere clause like so:

```
$konten = Konten::where('kategori', 'Announcement')
->orWhere('kategori', 'Activities')
->orderBy('id', 'desc')
->get();
```

Or as mentioned in answers below you can use whereIn statement.